# Querying Hornbill Supportworks database with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

We have Hornbill Supportworks Enterprise Support Platform 7.6.2 Professional Edition (Helpdesk application) with the database files in MySQL format (.myd .myi .frm) but do not have MySQL Server installed on the same machine.

I want to be able to query the Supportworks database like you can with a MSSQL database and SQL Management Studio to return information that the application seems incapable of providing. I presume there is more to it than just installing MySQL Server and importing the database files somehow.

I have no experience with MySQL or Supportworks so any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the Supportworks database from a variety of other tools; however you need to have some knowledge and configuration details and which are specific to the Hornbill product. I’d suggest you visit the Hornbill Forums to get some helpful information and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Ricky, do you know what any of these tools are?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, did not get a notification of your reply.  HeidiSQL is a good free tool that I would recommend.  You can download it from the following site: www.heidisql.com

Comment: @Ricky what is table for querying CHGS any idea

Answer (score 0):

A Standard Hornbill installation includes a custom mySQL server build (known as swSQL) and a commandline query tool (Interactive SQL).

The default install location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Hornbill\Core Services\SwSqlServer\`

Comment: @Slava.k what is the table name for the CHG in the database